# git command to get remote changes no matter what

Tags: git, version-control

I am stuck on that for long time and not able to find solution
I have branch called `master`.

I am in folder `application` with some older revision of master.

Now i want the command which replaces the current content of folder with latest code in remote master.

There can be many cases but i want to ignore all things below

1. There can be files modified locally
2. There can be untracked files
3. There can force push on master with completely new code
4. There can be untracaked files which are now in master so that when u pull there are chances of merge conflict with remote files
5. When u do git status it may say

   1. On branch master and uptodate
   2. On branch master ur branch and origin/master has diverged
   3. On branch master , current rebase in progress
   4. You are on detached head state
   5. You on branch dev

So for all those above cases i want to ignore and i just want latest code.

The easiest way is to delete the folder and clone

Another way is below and really thats dirty and don't want to do that

```
cd /application && git reset --hard && git rebase --abort | true && git checkout master && git fetch origin && git reset --hard  origin/master
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to check out origin/master. This avoids having to deal with the state of the local master branch and any merge issues.

```
# Abort a rebase, if any
git rebase --abort

# Fetch the latest from origin
git fetch origin

# Check it out and throw out any changes
git checkout -f origin/master

# Clean out all untracked files.
git clean -dxf
```

Comment: is it possible to reduce it to less commands. Alsi when we do git fetch origin then it fetches all branch , is it possible to git fetch origin/master only

Comment: @Karl, `git fetch origin master` to fetch `origin/master` only.

Comment: @karl AFAIK, this is it. Git is not a release tool. If you try to use it as one, well, this happens. Also while you can just fetch one branch, unless the other branches are wildly divergent there is little cost to fetching the rest.

Comment: @AndréSassi i tried `git fetch origin/master` i get this `fatal: 'origin/master' does not appear to be a git repository`

Comment: @Karl `origin/master` is the name of your local copy of the remote branch. `git fetch`, `git push`, and `git pull` all take the remote and the remote branch name separately. `git fetch origin master`. But again, for most repositories there is little cost to fetching all the branches.